# How to use build classifier (based on word embeddings) on new data for sentiment analysis?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, text2vec

So I used the `text2vec` R package to build word vectorizations for feature selection. I did that according to Dmitriy Selivanov's page http://text2vec.org/vectorization.html, which explains how to properly use `text2vec` before building a classifier.

This is my code:

```
# Loading packages and movie review data
require(text2vec)
require(data.table)
data("movie_review")
library(tidyverse)

# Converting list of movie reviews to data table by reference
setDT(movie_review)

# Sorting the data table by ID
setkey(movie_review, id)

#Set seed for reproducibe results
set.seed(2016L)

# Splitting data set into training and testing data 
all_ids = movie_review$id
train_ids = sample(all_ids, 4000)
test_ids = setdiff(all_ids, train_ids)
train = movie_review[J(train_ids)]
test = movie_review[J(test_ids)]

# Vocabulary-based vecorization 

# Define preprocessing function and tokenization function
# Setting up a pre-processing function
prep_fun <- function(x) {
x %>% 
# make text lower case
str_to_lower %>% 
# remove non-alphanumeric symbols
str_replace_all("[^[:alpha:]]", " ") %>% 
# collapse multiple spaces
str_replace_all("\\s+", " ")}

# Setting up the tokenization function
tok_fun = word_tokenizer

# Using an iterator over tokens to create the vocabulary
it_train = itoken(train$review, 
              preprocessor = prep_fun, 
              tokenizer = tok_fun, 
              ids = train$id, 
              progressbar = FALSE)
vocab = create_vocabulary(it_train)

# The created vocabulary consists of 35070 unique words.
# Now that the vocabulary is set up, it is time to construct a DTM.
# The vocab_vectorizer() function will create the vectors of the tokens.
vectorizer = vocab_vectorizer(vocab)
t1 = Sys.time()
dtm_train = create_dtm(it_train, vectorizer)
print(difftime(Sys.time(), t1, units = 'sec'))

# Vectorization and DTM creation of the training data is now complete.
# Looking up the dimensions of the created DTM
dim(dtm_train)
identical(rownames(dtm_train), train$id)
```

Then I went ahead to fit a LASSO regression model using the `glmnet`R package.

```
# Training the model using LASSO regression to avoid high variance in coefficients
require(glmnet)
NFOLDS = 4
t1 = Sys.time()
glmnet_classifier = cv.glmnet(x = dtm_train, y = train[['sentiment']], 
                          family = 'binomial', 
                          # L1 penalty
                          alpha = 1,
                          # interested in the area under ROC curve
                          type.measure = "auc",
                          # 5-fold cross-validation
                          nfolds = NFOLDS,
                          # high value is less accurate, but has faster training
                          thresh = 1e-3,
                          # again lower number of iterations for faster training
                          maxit = 1e3)
print(difftime(Sys.time(), t1, units = 'sec'))

# Since the classifier is now trained, it is possible to plot the area under the curve (AUC).
plot(glmnet_classifier)

# It is also possible to compute the AUC as a figure.
print(paste("max AUC =", round(max(glmnet_classifier$cvm), 4)))

# Now that the model has been fitted to the DTM, it is time for validating the model's performance on the test data.
# Therefore, the same preprocessing and tokenization functions will be applied as well as the same vectorizer function.

# Preprocessing and tokenizing test data
it_test = itoken(test$review, 
              preprocessor = prep_fun, 
              tokenizer = tok_fun, 
              ids = test$id, 
              progressbar = FALSE)

# Creating DTM of test data
dtm_test = create_dtm(it_test, vectorizer)

# Using classifier for prediction on test data
preds = predict(glmnet_classifier, dtm_test, type = 'response')[,1]
glmnet:::auc(test$sentiment, preds)
```

Now I would like to use the classifier on my own data to classify sentiments in my own data. My question is: Do I have to apply the same preprocessing and tokenizing function on my data and then also vectorize the words of my data? Or just simply use the built classifier on the data?

I really hope to find some answers thanks!

Comment: `Error in { : could not find function "%>%"`. Now I suspect it is obvious that I need either `magrittr` or `dplyr` when I get this, but it is still annoying to see errors that could have been avoided with fully reproducible code:  Not everyone loads `dplyr` or `tidyverse` at startup. As it turned out, neither `magrittr` nor `dplyr` were sufficient.

Comment: I'm now puzzled (after fixing the other error which was inconsequential) about what the question actually is. You appear to have created a model and then calculated and AUC statistic for a test set, so it appears you have "used the built classifier on the data".